# Under what conditions would the application state be in background inside of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Tags: ios, uikit

Suppose you're in `AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` and you check `UIApplication.shared.applicationState`. Occasionally but not often, `UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background`. What scenarios could cause this?

Comment: It depends on what background modes your app supports. It could be because of Bluetooth if you use core Bluetooth in the background or location if you use location in the background or a VoIP push if you use callkit push or even a silent remote notification.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. I can confirm that we have location updates. When the background state was `background`, I checked the launch options and there was a value for `location`. 

But the weird part: I launched the app manually by tapping the icon. Is it valid to launch the app manually, but for the state to be background and the launch options to have a value like location? As if it happened at the same time?

Do you know if there's a way to distinguish whether the launch was due to tapping the icon and not due to some background mode trigger (e.g. location, remote notification)?